# Key pressed event only responds Ctrl, Shift and Alt in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

So, i'm making a text editor with PyQt5, and i want to update the file every time a key is pressed. However, when i call the keyPressEvent(), it only responds when i click Ctrl, Alt, Shift, after i change the text on QPlaintextEdit.

The code is very big so i'll leave the part with the key press problem. My goal is to change the statusbar to Unsaved when a new key is pressed, so the manageStatusMessage will check if the current text is the same of the last saved file.

**Code**:

```
import os
import sys
from SideEditor import Rightclick
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

objects = ["Menu", "LineEdit", "Box", "MenuBar", "StatusBar"]


class TextEditor(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setObjectName(objects[0])
        self.txt_editor = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.txt_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.txt_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.menu = QMenuBar(self)
        self.pulled_file = None
        self.setMenuBar(self.menu)
        self.MenuBar()
        self.Actions()
        self.TxtField()
        self.makeStatusBar()
        Rightclick(self)

    def MenuBar(self):
        #  Main window

    def keyPressEvent(self, signal):
        self.manageStatusMessage()

    def manageStatusMessage(self):
        if self.pulled_file != None:
            self.check_file = open(self.pulled_file, "r").read()
            self.current_file = self.txt_editor.toPlainText()
            if self.check_file == self.current_file:
                pass
            else:
                self.currentStatus.setText("Unsaved")
        else:
            pass

    def makeStatusBar(self):
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.currentStatus = QLabel()
        self.currentStatus.setText("Unsaved")
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.currentStatus)
        self.currentStatus.setObjectName(objects[4])
```

Comment: Re-reading the file just to check whether the document has changed is horribly inefficient and unnecessary. Use the [modificationChanged signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#modificationChanged) and/or the [undo/redo available signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#undoAvailable).

Comment: @ekhumoro yes, but i still need to use the key press event to change the status bar, or can i connect these signals to save the files (if they're true)?

The problem is that manageStatusMessage does not recognizes text keys (abc, 123)

Comment: Why do you need to use key events at all? The built-in signals can be used to automatically update other parts of the gui when the document is actually modified (or goes back to its initial state). If you want a manual save shortcut, use [QShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html).

Comment: Alright, that seems better. Thank you for replying, i'll try it using the signals, since it's a lot more useful. :)